# Virtualmin Cloudflare SPF does not designate permitted sender hosts

Tags: dns, centos, cloudflare, spf, virtualmin

I'm using Virtualmin and Cloudflare for DNS.

Main domain has no issues with sending emails in inbox, but other domains on same IP get "does not designate permitted sender hosts" for SPF check from google.

I've set up SPF record in Cloudflare for the other domains adding include:maindomain.com but still getting the error.

What settings do I need to do on Virtualmin and Cloudflare so the other domains on my server pass the SPF check?

cloudflare txt record
v=spf1 ip4:86.127.60.59 include:honeybadger.it ~all

gmail error:
spf=none (google.com: host.honeybadger.it does not designate permitted sender hosts) smtp.mailfrom=vixo@host.honeybadger.it; <-- error

cloudflare txt record for main domain
v=spf1 ip4:86.127.60.59 ~all

google ok:
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of user@honeybadger.it designates 86.127.60.59 as permitted sender) client-ip=86.127.60.59; <-- main domain ok

Thank you.

I've tried restarting the server with all configurations with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Right, it was not a SPF issue, it was the website configuration to send via the default account email, had to just use a SMTP plugin configured with an email address, also the SPF records should be just "v=spf1 ip4:86.127.60.59
~all" allowing emails from the server IP